# Why is the email is not send in this code? Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.8

I am trying to send a email for a user when he fill a form and click the submit.I have created a controller in Magento and included the following code

```
public function sendMailAction(){
    $html="put your html content hereblah blah";
    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $mail->setToName('Your Name');
    $mail->setToEmail('sadeeenadeee@gmail.com');
    $mail->setBody('Mail Text / Mail Content');
    $mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
    $mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
    $mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
    $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

    try {
        $mail->send();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
        $this->_redirect('');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
        $this->_redirect('');
    }
    }
```

This is the function I am planning to use to send the email.Above controller function is called for the click of the submit button.
Then I configured the outgoing SMTP email in Magento admin panel.

**System > Configuration-> Mail Sending Settings**

I followed the above path and added the **HOST** and **PORT** in the Mail Sending Settings and saved the config.HOST and PORT are obtained from the email service provider.But when a user fills the form and click the submit,rather than sending a email browser tries to launch a app saying that,

***THIS LINK NEEDS TO BE OPEN WITH AN APPLICATION***

Can someone help me please?
**I AM WORKING ON A HOSTED SITE**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$EmailSenderName="Email Sender Name";
$EmailId="semder Email";
            $emailTemplateVariables['key1'] = "data1";
            $emailTemplateVariables['key2'] = "data2";


            /* sent mail to //recepient  */
            $recipientEmail="abcd@xyz.com";

            $sender = Array('name' => $EmailSenderName,
            'email' => $EmailId);
            $emailName = 'Email Name';
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                        ->loadDefault('Any_email_template');

                $emailTemplate->setSenderName($EmailSenderName)
                ->setSenderEmail($EmailId)
                ->setTemplateSubject($emailName);
                $emailstatus=$emailTemplate->send($recipientEmail, $emailName, $emailTemplateVariables);



            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
            if($emailstatus) {
//email send successfully

            }
            else {

            //something went wrong
            }
```

Please confirm that any mails in que for that enter the terminal command
mailq

```
 $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load(1);   //1 is Transactional Emails id
```

if you want to try default the above

Comment: Thanks I was wondering for few days and found that emails were in  a queue.That is why they are not delivered.I think its is a bug in my hosted server.THIS LINK NEEDS TO BE OPEN WITH AN APPLICATION message is due to is due to open alert window which I have used for testing in the js.I forgot about it.Thanks a lot.Now it is working

Comment: But I have a another problem.How to get away with this email getting in a queue problem.Any solutions?

Comment: Did you use any 3rd party extensions for emails...?

Comment: Please refer the  [blog](https://www.brihaspatitech.com/blog/delivering-emails-by-queue-troubleshooting-magento-emails-not-sending-issue/)